# not null enable novalidate issue in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a data existing in my table table_abc.

There is a column context_name which is non-mandatory but now I am trying to modify this column and make it mandaroty

for example :

```
ALTER TABLE table_abc MODIFY CONTEXT_NAME VARCHAR2(240) NOT NULL;
```

This will throw an error

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02296: cannot enable (APPS.) - null values found

So i used novalidate like

```
Alter table table_abc modify CONTEXT_NAME not null enable novalidate;
```

But now when i am seeing the structure of the table it is not showing context_ame as not null;

```
Name                  Null     Type           
--------------------- -------- -------------- 
NAME                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(700)  
ITEM_DESCRIPTION               VARCHAR2(2000) 

ITEM_TEXT_TL_15                VARCHAR2(4000) 
ITEM_DESCRLONG                 VARCHAR2(4000)     
CREATED_BY                     VARCHAR2(64)   
CREATION_DATE                  DATE           
LAST_UPDATE_DATE               DATE           
LAST_UPDATED_BY                VARCHAR2(64)   
LAST_UPDATE_LOGIN              VARCHAR2(32)   
CONTEXT_NAME                   VARCHAR2(240)   
BF_NAME          VARCHAR2(264)
```

Shouldnt context_name be not null ?

Comment: You need to get rid of the `NULL` values first.

Comment: I was actually trying to give a default value.. is there anyother wy out ? i do not want to touch the existing data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add a constraint, you have to update the values to meet that constraint, so that mean updating the table and fill in your desired default value in those rows that now contain null.

```
update table_abc 
set CONTEXT_NAME = '(none)' 
where CONTEXT_NAME is null
```

Alternatively, instead of changing the column to be mandatory, you could add a trigger to that table that validates the values. That way, you only verify the data when a row is inserted or modified.

```
create or replace trigger TABLE_ABC_IUB before insert or update
on TABLE_ABC for each row
begin
  if :new.CONTEXT_NAME is null then
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'CONTEXT_NAME is required');
  end if;
end;
```

This will require you to always fill in a value when you touch the row. You could refine the condition a little bit by allowing modification of rows that didn't have a CONTEXT_NAME to begin with. The trigger below should enforce a value for new rows and for rows that were updated from having a value to NULL.

```
create or replace trigger TABLE_ABC_IUB before insert or update
on TABLE_ABC for each row
begin
  if :new.CONTEXT_NAME is null and (inserting or :old.CONTEXT_NAME is not null) then
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'CONTEXT_NAME is required');
  end if;
end;
```

Instead of raising an exception, you are of course allowed to just assign a value to `:new.CONTEXT_NAME`.

Comment: @Goleztrol- I cannot update the existing value according to reqmt

Comment: @divya.trehan573 . . . You *have* to update the existing `NULL` values if you want a not-`NULL` constraint.